# how to make a multi-columns scroll bar menu look like an excel spreadsheet

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I would like to display a list of persons and make the first and last names in two separate columns. I should also be able to scroll vertically. It works fine, but I would like the screen to look like an excel spreadsheet. 
ie, I'm trying to display the title of each column , something like that :

```
  first     last
  John      Smith
  John      Doe
```

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MmLQL/11/
When I try to add the titles "first" and "last" and a horizontal line below , it adds them vertically :

```
first   john
last     Smith
john     Doe
```

Thanks you for your help!

Comment: Use ul and li(s). also IDs of div columns must not be same. In Javascript you can track number of li(s) in div_column1 equal to number of lis(s) in div_column2. Also Keep header in separate div. In case you want to sort the li(s) of specific column. If you dig more you can also add new li dynamically on click of button with a new content from ajax or hidden element etc.

Comment: The multi-column module is not for creating grids, its for newspaper/magazine style columns.  You've grouped your elements together based on how they look rather than their relationship.  This looks like tabular data.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/MmLQL/19/

Comment: @cinammon and hima , thank you for your answer. Didn't pay attention that I was using the same id twice, sorry guys. I'm not looking for create grids, I would like a table without any vertical nor horizontal separation between cells

Comment: @user1499220 so don't use borders?  Don't make bad design choices based on default appearances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should not use id twice, but anyway you can try this :

```
#div_all_columns
{

   -moz-column-count: 2;
   -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2
    width: 380x; 
    padding: 10px;  
    display: table;
}

#div_column
{  
    font-size:90%;
    display: table-row-group;
    margin:4px;
}

p
{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

restructure your code as below

```
<div runat="server" id="div_scroll">
   <div runat="server" id="div_all_columns">

        <div runat="server" id="div_column">
            <p >First</p>
            <p> John </p><p> John </p> <p>John </p>
       </div>
         <div runat="server" id="div_column">
             <p >Last</p>
             <p>Smith </p><p>Doe </p> <p>Smith </p>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Add an extra class to the css as below

```
div p
{
   border:solid 1px black;

}
```

Hope it is as you expected

Answer (score 0):

This is tabular data, use a table.

http://jsfiddle.net/MmLQL/26/

```
<div runat="server" id="div_scroll">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

#div_scroll {
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
}

#div_scroll table {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 90%;
}

#div_scroll thead {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this **[Fiddle_Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh38/MmLQL/28/)**

### HTML code:

```
<div runat="server" id="div_scroll">
   <div runat="server" id="div_all_columns">
        <div runat="server" id="div_column" class="inner_div">
            <span style="border:3px solid green; font-size:20px">
                FirstName
            </span>
            <p> John <br/> John  <br/> John <br/></p>
       </div>
         <div runat="server" id="div_column" class="inner_div">
            <span style="border:3px solid green; font-size:20px">
                LastName
            </span>
            <p>Smith <br/>Doe <br/> Smith</p>
       </div>         
   </div>
</div>
```

### CSS code:

```
#div_scroll {
overflow: auto;
//max-width: 100px; 
//max-height: 50px; 
}

.inner_div {
overflow: scroll;
width:120px;
height: 80px;
}

#div_all_columns
{

-moz-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
column-count: 2;

width: 280px; 
//padding: 10px;  
}

#div_column
{  font-size:90%;
   margin:4px;
}
p
{
    text-align: justify;
}
```

The o/p is as follows-

[image: o/p]